# How to know when a processingjs sketch has been loaded?

Tags: javascript, jquery, processing

I have written my own sketch in processing and inserted it on the page using processingjs and ajax like so:

```
$.getScript("js/libs/processingjs.js", function() {
    $('#sketch').each(function() {
        Processing.loadSketchFromSources(this, [$(this).data('processing-sources')]);

    });
});
```

here is the canvas `#sketch` is referring to:

```
<canvas data-processing-sources="first-sketch.pde" id='sketch'></canvas>
```

This works, however I also want to interact with the sketch using Javascript. When I type this in my (firebug) console everything works great:

```
var sketch = Processing.getInstanceById('sketch');
sketch.addTweet(30, 30, 100);
```

(addTweet is a function of the sketch, which is available once the sketch has been loaded)
But when I put it inside the javascript like so:

```
$.getScript("js/libs/processingjs.js", function() {
    $('#sketch').each(function() {
        Processing.loadSketchFromSources(this, [$(this).data('processing-sources')]);


        var sketch = Processing.getInstanceById('sketch');
        sketch.addTweet(30, 30, 100);

    });
});
```

I get the error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'addTweet' of undefined
```

I think the sketch has not been loaded at this point, is there a callback or a proper way to run code once it has loaded?

I receive the same error when including the processingjs lib in a `script` tag. and running the code on jQuery.ready.

Comment: Seems this has not been resolved yet. [Here is some insight](https://processing-js.lighthouseapp.com/projects/41284/tickets/1887).

Comment: I would suggest simply polling `setInterval` until the instance no longer returns `undefined`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is something I put together for a project of mine. It's not pretty, but it gets the job done (for now).

```
var timer = 0,
    timeout = 3000,
    mem = setInterval(function () {
        var sketch = Processing.getInstanceById("processingCanvas");
        if (sketch) {
            console.log("SKETCH HAS LOADED");
            clearInterval(mem);
        } else {
            timer += 10;
            if (timer > timeout) {
                console.log("FAILED TO LOAD SKETCH");
                clearInterval(mem);
            }
        }
    }, 10);
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that loadSketchFromSources is not synchronous.

A callback has been added (github, latest) to the loadSketchFromSources function. So you can write your code as:

```
$.getScript("js/libs/processingjs.js", function() {
    $('#sketch').each(function() {
        Processing.loadSketchFromSources(this, [$(this).data('processing-sources')], function(sketch) {
          sketch.addTweet(30, 30, 100);
        });
    });
});
```

You can also use a class instead of an id. Grab the sketch in the callback and you don't need to use `getInstanceById`.

Comment: Awesome to see this was added eventually :)